Deleted my secret phrase, didn't note it, I can only watch my account now!
I recently deleted my secret phrase because I thought that my account would work without it. Now I am in spectator mode. Does anybody know how I can get my wallet back without the secret phrase or private key. If thats not possible then I lost over 120$. Please does anybody know a way?
